# How can I reduce duplicate code in Hibernate classes?

Tags: java, hibernate

At this point we have several Hibernate object classes in our project, like the following:

```
package org.carl.recordkeeper.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class BstRecordPK implements Serializable
{
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

private String bst;

private Integer instbit;

// --------------------- GETTER / SETTER METHODS ---------------------

@Id
@Column( name = "BST", nullable = false, length = 1 )
public String getBst()
{
    return bst;
}

public void setBst( String bst )
{
    this.bst = bst;
}

@Id
@Column( name = "INSTBIT", nullable = false )
public Integer getInstbit()
{
    return instbit;
}

public void setInstbit( Integer instbit )
{
    this.instbit = instbit;
}

// ------------------------ CANONICAL METHODS ------------------------

@Override
public boolean equals( Object o )
{
    if ( this == o )
    {
        return true;
    }
    if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    BstRecordPK that = (BstRecordPK)o;

    if ( bst != null ? !bst.equals( that.bst ) : that.bst != null )
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ( instbit != null ? !instbit.equals( that.instbit ) : that.instbit != null )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    int result = instbit != null ? instbit.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + ( bst != null ? bst.hashCode() : 0 );
    return result;
}
}
```

We also have a duplicate code checker, which keeps going off when we create a new Hibernate class because one of the get/set pairs matches what's in another class (database tables with foreign keys). Is there a way to reduce duplicate code and still keep Hibernate happy? I've thought about using a base class, but it's not like there is a single column used in all the database tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code duplication warning a meant to show copied sections of code normally produced with copy & paste. Copying code will reduce maintainability and may result in security issues.

If sonarqube shows me duplication warnings, I have a closer look on the section of fode and decide, if this is a false positive in sense that many pojos will share some code like `getId() { return id; }` even if the retrn type differs or I some programmer just re-implemented or copied a section.

I would strongly recommend to not reduce you entities. This will only lead to objuscation.

However, you can try to use `@MappedSuperClass` if you really bother about code dublication detection limitations.

Comment: Ah, @MappedSuperClass works quite well actually, thank you.

Also, it's not just about "copy and paste", it's about code maintainability.